# Given a vector space $V$, why is the dual space $V^*$ interesting?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I can't help but think that I still don't get the big picture about the dual space of a finite vector space. I would like to first show what I understand, and ask for feedback on what I'm lacking or misunderstood. Then, I would also like to know why is the dual space interesting.

Given a finite vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$, with basis $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$, we have $V^*=\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$ the space of all linear functions $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$, with basis $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^n, f_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$. We can then have:

$$
\forall f \in V^*, f = \alpha_1 f_1 + ... + \alpha_n f_n.
$$

But I also like to think that:

$$
\forall f\in V^*, f = f(v_1)f_1 + ... + f(v_n)f_n,
$$

because given $v \in V, v = a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n$,

$$
f(v) = a_1f(v_1)+...+a_nf(v_n)=f(v_1)f_1(v)+...+f(v_n)f_n(v).
$$

But I'm not sure in why is this helpful. Also I have also seen the isomorphism $\varphi:V\rightarrow V^*$, where we take $\varphi(v_i)=f_i$, and so we get that $\forall v \in V,v = a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n$, we get a corresponding vector in $V^*, f = a_1f_1 + ... + a_nf_n$. So, we can identify an element of $V$ with an element of $V^*$, but I don't understand why is this helpful.

**Edit:** Okay, so I found [Andrea Mori's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172022/relationship-between-a-vector-space-v-and-its-dual-space-v) answer, his 3rd point is interesting. I did read about his answer before asking this, but I didn't understand it the first time I read it. I would love to see more answers though, helps my understanding.

Comment: One of the (numerous) things that make the dual space a very useful tool is the correspondance between hyperplanes in $V$ and lines in $V^*$. It gives another point of view on a lot of reduction question.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe can you please elaborate more, or point me to some material? I'm a 5th semester pure math undergraduate

Comment: Duality is a deep mathematical concept in general, not only here for vector spaces.

Comment: I think the usual approach to dual spaces in most treatments of finite-dimensional linear algebra obscures the big picture. You might find my video helpful: https://youtu.be/eOIJzb7SItg

Comment: @DietrichBurde I can't help but think so, I have encountered duals several times, such as the dual of a linear program (we went through the geometry for the primal, not for the dual), or topological and algebraic duals of a graph. Each time it just exists, and we use it, but I don't understand a deeper meaning of it.