# a vector space and its dual

Tags: vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Is the identifiaction between a vector space $V$ and its **first dual** $V^*$ **functorial** ?
How can I see either positive or negative answer ?

**EDIT**
At least with the use of a scalar product!

Comment: To be precise, you also need to specify how the morphisms are mapped. There is a natural way to define this mapping such that you get a (contravariant) functor.

Comment: But this is not an "identification" of $V$ with $V^*$.  And when $V$ is infinite-dimensional, $V$ is not even isomorphic to $V^*$.

Comment: @GEdgar Good. Stick with finite dimensionals $V$.

Comment: @GEdgar But please see the **EDIT**.

Comment: @user122424 what do you mean by the scalar product? Do you mean $v \cdot w = v^T w$. In that case the answer is yes because we can see from the definition that defining a scalar product is equivalent to defining a map $(\cdot)^T : V \to V^*$ given by $v \mapsto v^T$.

Comment: In other words, we have the rather uninspiring answer that if we specify a functor from $V$ to $V^*$ then the relationship between $V$ and $V^*$ is functorial. But there is no natural such functor. The map $v \mapsto v^T$ is basis dependent.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I think that you've solved my entire problem.

Comment: @user122424 it occurs to me that the specification of such a functor for general finite dimensional vector spaces probably requires the axiom of choice. Essentially we have to pick a basis for each vector space and define our functor as the usual row-column swap once we've written each vector down as components in the chosen basis for its vector space. Picking a basis for each vector space is highly noncanonical.

Comment: As a final comment, note that there is a functor from vector spaces $V$ to their double duals $V^{**}$ (note however that $V$ and $V^{**}$ are only *isomorphic* in the finite dimensional case). Set $F(v)w = w(v)$ for $v \in V$ and $w \in V^*$. You still have to do a little checking and unwinding of definitions, but that's the idea. No finite dimensional restriction necessary.

Comment: Sorry, final final comment. Any functor from $V$ to $V^*$ should be a contravariant functor, as you can check.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Relationship between a vector space V and its dual space V*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172022/977780)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a real inner product space $( V, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ there is a natural map from $V$ to $V^*$.  Namely, vector $u \in V$ goes to linear functional $\phi_u \in V^*$ defined by $\phi_u(x) = \langle x,u\rangle$.  In case $V$ is finite-dimensional, this is an isomorphism from $V$ to $V^*$.  Make it a (contravariant) functor as usual: if $T : V_1 \to V_2$ is a linear transformation, then $T^* : V_2 \to V_1$ satisfies
$$
\langle T(x),u \rangle = \langle x,T^*(u)\rangle .
$$
That is, with functionals as above, $T^* : V_2^* \to V_1^*$ is
$$
T^*(\alpha) = \alpha\circ T,\quad\text{for }\alpha \in V_2^*
$$

**EDIT:** Does this n.t. commutativity square make sense ?
How can I justify that it does and that it really commutes ?

$$\begin{array}{ccc} V_1 & \rightarrow  & V_1^* \\ {T} \downarrow && \ \ \ \uparrow {T^*}\\ V_2 & \rightarrow & V_2^* \end{array}\tag1$$

**added**
No, $(1)$ is certainly wrong.  If $V_1$ is $\mathbb R^2$ with the Euclidean norm, then we can think of $V_1$ as $1 \times 2$ matrices, and the correspondence $^*$ lets us think of $V_1^*$ as $1\times 2$ matrices.  The horizontal arrows map each vector to its transpose.  If $T : V_1 \to V_2$ is represented by a $2 \times 2$ matrix acting on the left, then $T^*$ is the transpose matrix acting on the right.  For example, if $T = 2I$, twice the identity, then in $(1)$ the arrow across the top is the transpose, while the composition around the other three sides is $4$ times the transpose.

Comment: Could you please state what does it mean now that ${}^*$ **is functorial** ? At best, if you could draw the fully labelled commutative square.

Comment: I guess "functorial" would mean $1_{V}^* = 1_{V^*}$ and $(S\circ T)^* = T^*\circ S^*$.

Comment: I think you are right. How would you prove this is the case for your ${}^*$ ?

Comment: Why not try to do it yourself?

Comment: I can prove $(S\circ T)^*=T^*\circ S^*$ but what I need is a **commutative naturality square**.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT** to your question. There I've summarized all my doubts about the problem. In particular instead of $V_1$ I should have written $F(x)$ and similarly $G(x),F(y)$  and $G(y)$ for some functors $F$ and $G$ but I do not know which I'm rather confused ...

Comment: The OP is about "functorial", not about "naturality".

Comment: I thought that functorial means **naturality square commutes for every functors images** of  any map $x\to y$ ??